# Quiero imprimir el Siguiente reporte visualidado con (crystalreport viewer)

Tags: vb.net

**esta es la pantalla donde visualiso el crystal report**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Quiero generar un reporte para guardarlo e imprimirlo al mismo tiempo**
 *Uso el siguiente código para *imprimir. ( el codigo siguiente es proporcionado por uno de mis compañeros, dice el que si funciona pero a mi no 
 no se cual sea la diferencia**

```
Dim Message As String
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = conexion
    Try
        Dim comando As New SqlCommand
        comando.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO 
    Dim cn2 As New SqlConnection
    'Dim encontro As String
    cn2.ConnectionString = conexion
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand()
    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Dictamen ORDER BY id DESC "
    Label1.Text & "'"
    cmd2.Connection = cn2
    cn2.Open()
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        encontro = True
        Label2.Text() = dr.Item("id").ToString()
    End While
    Response.Redirect("reportedictamen.aspx?id=" & Label2.Text & "")
End Sub
```

** Al momento de dar imprimir  manda a una pagina en blanco**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*¿alguna solución?*

**Y el siguiente Codigo en Crystal Viewer**

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Data
    Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports
    Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
    Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Public Class reportedictamen
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim conexion As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Dictamen").ConnectionString
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load       
        Dim ireport As New ReportDocument()
        ireport = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        Dim iConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
        iConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "(base de datos)"
        iConnectionInfo.UserID = "(Usuario)"
        iConnectionInfo.Password = "(Pass)"
        iConnectionInfo.ServerName = "(Ip del servidor)"
        iConnectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL
        ireport.FileName = "D:\sistemas\net\Dictamenes\Dictamenes\reportes\CrystalReport1.rpt"
        SetDBLogonForReport(iConnectionInfo, ireport)
        ireport.RecordSelectionFormula = "{dictamen.id} = " & Request.QueryString("id") & ""
        Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ireport

    End Sub
    Private Sub SetDBLogonForReport(ByVal myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo, ByVal myReportDocument As ReportDocument)
        'salto
        Dim myTables As Tables = myReportDocument.Database.Tables
        '-
        For Each myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In myTables
            Dim myTableLogonInfo As TableLogOnInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo
            myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo
            myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myTableLogonInfo)
        Next
    End Sub
```

*Si alguien puede darme soporte por discord o por Facebook le agredeceria mucho*